# Rails Join based on multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have four models in question: `User`, `Product`, `Purchase`, and `WatchedProduct`.

I am trying to get a list of products that meet one of the following criteria:

1. I created the product.
2. I bought the product.
3. The product is free, and I have "starred" or "watched" it.

This is what I have so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def special_products
    product_ids = []

    # products I created
    my_products = Product.where(:user_id => self.id).pluck(:id)
    # products I purchased
    my_purchases = Purchase.where(:buyer_id => self.id).pluck(:product_id)
    # free products I watched
    my_watched = WatchedProduct.where(:user_id =>self.id).joins(:product).where(products: { price: 0 }).pluck(:product_id)

    product_ids.append(my_products)
    product_ids.append(my_purchases)
    product_ids.append(my_watched)

    product_ids # yields something like this => [[1, 2], [], [2]]

    # i guess at this point i'd reduce the ids, then look them up again...

    product_ids.flatten!
    product_ids & product_ids
    products = []
    product_ids.each do |id|
      products.append(Product.find(id))
    end
    products

  end
end
```

What I am trying to do is get a list of `Product` models, not a list of IDs or a list of ActiveRecord Relations. I am very new to joins, but is there a way to do all of this in a single join instead of 3 queries, reduce, and re lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I like adding few scopes

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :free, -> { where(price: 0) }
  scope :bought_or_created_by, lambda do |user_id|
    where('user_id = :id OR buyer_id = :id', id: user_id)
  end
end
class WatchedProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_user, ->(user_id) { where(user_id: user_id) }
end
```

Then the queries

```
special_products = (Product.bought_or_created_by(id) + Product.joins(:watched_products).free.merge(WatchedProduct.by_user(id)).uniq
```

This will return an array of unique products using 2 queries.

Comment: `buyer_id` belongs to a `Purchase` model. Should I just moved the third scope to that model?

Comment: o yea, that's my mistake, i'll fix my answer

Comment: those are just to simplify the query, if it's not working then the only part that needs fixing is `Product.joins(:watched_products)`, what's the relation between `product` and `watched_products` ?

Comment: what part needed fixing?

Comment: if this code is inside the controller then yes, but if it's inside the model then id by it self will refer to the id of the instance of the user.

Comment: I ended up creating a few more scopes and doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Although i am not sure about your model associations but yes you can do all these things in single query somehow like this:

```
Product.joins([{:user => :watched_products}, :buyer, :purchases]).where(["users.id = :current_buyer && buyers.id = :current_buyer && watched_products.user_id = :current_buyer && purchases.buyer_id = :current_buyer, products.price = 0", :current_buyer => self.id])
```

I am assuming

```
Product belongs_to user and buyer
Product has_many purchases
User has_many watched_products
```